# pushviewcontroller is not working in ios7

Tags: ios, objective-c

first time VC1 to VC2 [self.navigationController pushViewController:mainView animated:YES] is working fine. From VC2 to VC3 is not working in ios7.

VC1->VC2 (working fine)

```
- (IBAction)loginBtnAction:(id)sender
{

    GVMainViewController *mainView;
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        mainView = [[GVMainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GVMainViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    } else
    {
        mainView = [[GVMainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GVMainViewController_iPad" bundle:nil] ;
    }

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:mainView animated:YES];
}
```

VC2->VC3 (NOt working)

```
- (IBAction)doneButtonAction:(id)sender
{
    [[FinishViewController getsharedInstance]updateProfileInfo];
    [self performSelector:@selector(moveTo) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];

}

- (void)moveTo
{
    GVMainViewController *mainView;
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        mainView = [[GVMainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GVMainViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];

    } else
    {
        mainView = [[GVMainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GVMainViewController_iPad" bundle:nil] ;
    }

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:mainView animated:YES];
}
```

and also getting some log **Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.** in all iOS versions, But In ios7 it is not pushing the view controller.

Please any one tell me the solution clearly for iOS7 and lower versions. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: in iOS7 you cannot push a new view-controller into the navigation stack until the previous animation is done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mainView should be pushed on main thread as performSelector initiates background thread.

```
- (void)moveTo
{
    GVMainViewController *mainView;
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
         mainView = [[GVMainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GVMainViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];

    } 
    else
    {
        mainView = [[GVMainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GVMainViewController_iPad" bundle:nil] ;
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:mainView animated:YES];
    });
}
```

Comment: the Apple has a different opinion about `–performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`: _This method sets up a timer to perform the `aSelector` message on the **current** thread’s run loop_... just saying.